# how to use map function to make const in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a lots of const. so I am gonna think use map function.

```
export default function cook(){
 const name = useInput("")
 const phone = useInput("")
 const birth = useInput("")
}
```

this code i use map function.

```
 const sections = [
 { key: "닉네임", to: "name" },
 { key: "폰", to: "phone" },
 { key: "생일", to: "birth" },
];

export default function cook(){
  sections.map((section) => (
  const section.to = useInput("")
}))
```

it show unexpected token. i can't understand.
could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the cook function.  We don't have the useInput function to test but

```
` export default function cook(){
   sections.map((section) => (
    section.to = useInput("")
))}`
```

doesn't throw an error. Essentially you've got your closing brackets mis-ordered.